# How to delete an item from UICollectionView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am showing images on a `collection view`.I want to delete each item on a `button click`.Now I am able to delete the item on `didSelect method`.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.colleVIew deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
}
```

I have placed button on `CollectionCell` and can find out the `indexpath.row` `on click`.But how to delete

```
-(void)chat:(int)i 
{
    NSLog(@"index path%d",i);
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:i]; // array object is getting removed,how to delete the CollectionviewCell
}
```

Comment: try using `reload data` or `reloadItemsAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do know the section as well:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
[self.colleVIew deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[indexPath]]];
```

Comment: you are sabotaging yourself with this: `NSLog(@"index path%d",i);`That's not the indexPath. At the best that's where the **row** you want to remove is located. That's normal, because you are hard coding the values of the row in the values that are inside of the  array. Instead of doing that, get the index by getting the position of the object, like this: `[array indexOfObject:theObjectIWantToRemove];`

Comment: but after reloading the collectionview,its OK.But the animation of cells rearrange after deletion is not ther..

Answer (score 1):

Just `reloadData` and make sure your `array` is used in `numberOfItemsInSection`. This will reload `dataSource`.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [yourArray count];
}

-(void)chat:(int)i 
{
    NSLog(@"index path%d",i);
    [yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:i]; 
     // array object is getting removed,how to delete the CollectionviewCell
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```